# wordpress cannot delete media file error message: you are not allowed to delete this post

Tags: php, wordpress, media

Good day!

ive been working on this wordpress problem for several days ive tried to ask on wordpress forum but still i got no answer. so the best option is to go here.

im tryin to delete some of my unused image on my blog and all image files would give Edit and View options but not the Delete Permanently option so i tried using bulk action to delete permanently the selected file. but unfortunately upon clicking the apply button it redirects into an error message sayin : you're not allowed to delete this post.

what could be the possible solution for this? your ideas are greatly appreciated. thanks a lot cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

At first look it seems you have a permission issue, but if you're sure your profile has administrator privileges try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/cleanup-images/

It scans for images not used in your WP installation then gives you the option to delete them en masse.